# What would be the research advances if we discover the gravitational waves?

Tags: gravity, particle-physics, gravitational-waves

As researchers of LIGO (USA) and VIRGO (France/Italy) say that they have discovered gravitational waves thanks to black hole collision today, what would be, apart of the important confirmation of Einstein's relativity theory, the possible advances it could bring to science (research)? Will it help to find the particle responsible of the gravity?

Comment: I think the primary purpose is to further confirm GR and the universal "speed limit." I also think that all possible answers will begin with "I think," "I expect," etc. I. e. the question is rather broad and opinion-based, and thus off-topic. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: It's important to note that no one from either LIGO or VIRGO has as yet gone on the record to confirm what are for now pure rumours of such a discovery. To quote the Louisiana head of LIGO: “We analyze our data. If there’s anything interesting we write it up in papers. We send the papers to the journals. If and only if there’s an interesting discovery that passes muster, and it has been accepted for publication by a journal, then we blab about it. Anything before that, you’re not going to get anything out of me.”

Comment: For a more recent update, see e.g. [this *Science* news report](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/02/woohoo-email-stokes-rumor-gravitational-waves-have-been-spotted), which makes it clear that everything is still on rumour status.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thank you for bringing details. In science rigor is mandatory  so it is important to precise the discovery. Thanks!

Comment: The confirmation of gravitational waves all by itself is only a "Uh-hum...", at best. The absence of gravitational waves, that would be a physical shocker. Until they have boosted their experiments to even lower noise and a significant amount of data about these events has been accumulated, there isn't really much science here. Having said that, these aren't discovery experiments. They are set up as precision observatories that are still pretty far away from their full potential. This is all still learning curve.

Comment: Further update: [LIGO has scheduled a press conference, Thursday, Feb. 11, at 10:30am EST](http://www.ligo.org/news/media-advisory.php).

Comment: @CuriousOne It is still something that would verify Einstein theory (what we weren't able to do till now) and accelerate science in the gravitation domain (more investments for gravitational measurements if we know that gravity exists thanks to relativity). But of course knowing that these waves wouldn't exist would have much more repercussions.

Comment: PMC, the discovery of grav. waves will allow us to "hear" the Universe and observe lots of new things, or old things in new ways, see e.g. http://motls.blogspot.com/2016/02/what-gravitational-wave-astronomy-may.html?m=1